# Function returning undefined when exported

Tags: javascript, events, eventemitter, module-export

I created a module in node.js that has 2 functions - takeInput and getEventEmitter. Both of them are exported. But when I require it is some other file, takeInput works fine but getEventEmitter turns out to be undefined.

Here are the codes:-

```
// main module.js
function takeInput(db) {
    // logic to take input from user
}

function getEventEmitter(db) {
    const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    console.log(takeInput);
    eventEmitter.on('function execution complete', () => takeInput(db));

    eventEmitter.emit('function execution complete');
}

module.exports = {
    takeInput,
    getEventEmitter
}
```

module where main module.js is exported

```
const { getEventEmitter } = require('main module');

// Some lines of code ...
getEventEmitter(db); // Error here when this function is called.
```

The error is as follows

```
TypeError: getEventEmitter is not a function
```

Please help.

Comment: You have nothing in the (shown) code that actually exports the function?

Comment: @Bergi Yupp my bad forgot to add that line. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export those 2 functions from main module.js

```
function takeInput(db) {
    // logic to take input from user
}

function getEventEmitter(db) {
    const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    console.log(takeInput);
    eventEmitter.on('function execution complete', () => takeInput(db));
    eventEmitter.emit('function execution complete');
}

export  { takeInput, getEventEmitter }
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Yes it has been exported. When i import it takeInput works fine but getEventEmitter throws TypeError.